# Remove shipping calculations from cart

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I remove the shipping calculations from the cart of my store?
This is the site: tintinportintin.com.br

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On line 89 in app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout.xml you wil find:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
```

This line is responsible for showing that block. You can copy this XML file to your own theme and remove this line.

But you can also use the `<checkout_cart_index>` handle and remove it. This can be done in local.xml for example.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping" />
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Using local.xml is the proper way of removing it, you shouldn't overwrite any of core xml files.