# Getting Payment transaction Failed even though it has not

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Everytime someone orders from my website I get the following email

Payment transaction failed.
Reason
Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order.

Checkout Type
onepage

But the order does complete.

I have tested it and even if I check the boxes to agree with the terms and conditions it still comes.

Joe

Comment: Did you get answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

We've got a similar error. At checkout, the customer have the possibility to calculate their estimated shipping and taxes. If the customer starts filling out the form and he/she may leaves a field empty, she/he can't finish shopping, despite correct adress, payment method etc. If they try to checkout no error message appears, but you as the shop owner receives a transaction failed email every time the customer hits the "place order"-button a la:

TRANSACTION FAILED
Reason:
Please enter the city.

So either, you try to fix this somehow or just disable the feature:
[Remove shipping calculations from cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371484/remove-shipping-calculations-from-cart)

I guess this causes only with a few magento themes, before we had changed our theme we did not get any transaction failed messages.